# In Vim, how would I replace the only the first occurrence of a certain word in each line with another word?

Tags: vim

***For instance, if I had:***

eat eat eat eat cake cake

eat eat eat cake

cake eat eat cake

**How would I only the first instance of cake in each line with pear?**

eat eat eat eat pear cake

eat eat eat pear

pear eat eat cake

Answer (score 33):

Use following

```
:%s/cake/pear/
```

Note that if you append 'g' flag to the above expression, the search happens **globally** over the **entire line**. The initial '%' character indicates the range over which the replacement should happen. % means whole file (or all lines in the file).

So following does replacement of only first occurrence on each line

```
:%s/cake/pear/
```

And following does replacement of all occurrences on each line

```
:%s/cake/pear/g
```

Comment: `g` stands for global. You can read more on the s(ubstitute) function in vim (and other flags like g) with `:help substitute`

Comment: It's worth noting that if `gdefault` is set, the meaning of the trailing `g` flag is inverted. See `:help 'gdefault`.